# How do you update curl on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, android, curl, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have an issue where I cannot develop on my Windows device because the curl that comes bundled with it produces

```
next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326)
```

How do I know Windows curl is to blame?

Because I tried the request in git bash using the `curl` that comes with it and it worked with no issues. Then I tried the same request in `cmd` and in `Postman` and it failed. This issue has effectively shut down my ability to test an android app that's being developed.

So ... How do you update `curl` for Windows?

Does it show up under apps? No.

This is on Windows 10, mind you, so there's a `curl.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Let's see ... can I put the `curl.exe` that comes with `Git` into the `PATH` variable?

Yes, I can, but it just gets ignored

Can I manually copy the `curl.exe` from `Git` to `C:\Windows\System32`?

Of course not. Administrators don't have the right to copy or rename or do anything with files therein, it seems, even after it's asked for permission.

Or alternatively, can I somehow make Android-Studio / its emulator use the "correct" `curl.exe`?

Comment: @vssher you didn't read the question, did you? I want to update curl `7.55.1` that comes with Windows to curl `curl 7.68.0` that comes with `Git` s.t. I can do some testing with the Android emulator. I don't want to install yet another curl version that won't resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you put the git curl in the path **before** (ie in front of) `C:\Windows\System32`

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that. Install curl in another folder and add it to the path before `c:\windows\system32`.

That way you will use the updated version without having to mess with the SO security.

Comment: This solution works great for the Windows cmd utility but be aware that Windows powershell will stubbornly ignore the PATH setting, whether your local curl install is referenced above it (or not) and continue to use the version installed in C:\windows\system32. I discovered this when
>curl -V produced a prompt for a URL, rather than printing the version info.

Comment: Hi @Grindlay, with powershell, you can see what command you are using with the `get-command` commandlet. Powershell respects the path the same way `cmd` does, but it's very often some script in your profile (and powershell has 4 profile locations, that can be changing your path... To be sure, type `$Env:PATH` in your console and you will see the PATH you are currently using... Just type `$Env:PATH=<curl path>;$Env:Path` and you will be fine...

Comment: Thanks for this. The entry `'D:\curl-7.78'` (the version I want) appears twice in my PATH env variable, but so does `'C:\Windows\System32'` . If I do:
`echo %PATH%` in a CMD window, I get identical output to Powershell.
Powershell is using the Windows cURL, CMD is using the version in `'D:\curl-7.78'`
I'm at a loss to explain this behaviour.